# How subscribers can receive data from Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

I am studying a use case with Microsoft Azure in mind, not sure can I achieve it with MS Azure or should I use other technology/platform. Here is the short description of my case, hope some body can point me what would be easier technology or solution in this case and where to start it.
0 to N number of users can insert data from 0 to N number of PCs/Devices to MS Azure from anywhere in the world. Now there might be 0 to N number of corresponding clients anywhere in the world to consume data. When ever user 1 inserts data that should be push to consumer 1 (if consumer 1 is connected to Azure). [image]

Comment: Azure as a platform provides many services that can be used to accomplish your objective. For your requirement, I would recommend reading up of services like Event Hubs, Notification Hubs, Service Bus Topics & Subscriptions and see which one of you would work best for you.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have some knowledge about Azure Service Bus. Could you point me some code example that can check if a suitable client connected, or get notified when a client is connected and pass the data to the client? Do I need to develop kind of worker role for this or only configuration is enough?